# Looking for a better way to write this css grid (scss)

Tags: reactjs, sass, css-grid

I have the following grid: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-bwy6v?file=/src/index.js and Im looking for a better/shorter way to write this grid.
My first time using a grid.
This is actually a small part of a responsive website that i'm building.
[image]

```
.addTransaction {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;

  & div {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }

  & .buySell {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
    column-gap: 5px;

    & .sell {
      width: 100%;
    }

    & .buy {
      width: 100%;
    }

  }

  & .token {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }


  & .quantity {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
  }

  & .price {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
  }

  & .date {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 1;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
  }

  & .exchange {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 4;
    grid-row-end: 5;
  }

  & .totalSpent {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 5;
    grid-row-end: 6;
  }

  & .addToCalc {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 6;
    grid-row-end: 7;
  }

  & .submit {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 7;
    grid-row-end: 8;
  }
}
```

```
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";

const App = () => (
  <div className={styles.addTransaction}>
    <div className={styles.buySell}>
      <div>
        <button className={styles.buy}>BUY</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className={styles.sell}>SELL</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={styles.token}>token</div>
    <div className={styles.quantity}>quantity</div>
    <div className={styles.price}>price</div>
    <div className={styles.date}>date</div>
    <div className={styles.exchange}>exchange</div>
    <div className={styles.totalSpent}>totalSpent</div>
    <div className={styles.addToCalc}>addToCalc</div>
    <div className={styles.submit}>submit</div>
  </div>
);
```

Please suggest a better way
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to make it shorter:

- CSS grids auto-flow, so you don't need to specify *every* row and column unless you're reordering cells
- For the cells that span two columns, you can use the shorthand syntax:

  ```css
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
  ```
- If you have a lot of cells with the same property (e.g. spanning two columns), you can add a common class name for them. If that isn't an option, you can also chain multiple selectors with a comma to add common properties:

  ```css
  .firstClass, .secondClass { example-property: 4px; }
  ```

The result is a lot shorter

```css
.addTransaction {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;

  & div {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }

  & .buySell {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
    column-gap: 5px;

    & .buy,
    & .sell {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }

  & .buySell,
  & .token,
  & .totalSpent,
  & .addToCalc,
  & .submit {
    grid-column: auto / span 2;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-and-scss-forked-t8hcw?file=/src/styles.module.scss

Some other options:

- consider `.grid-template-areas` for really complex layouts. It can be a readability lifesaver over manually specifying `grid-column` or `grid-row` multiple times.
- Should only the first row have a gap? You can add that gap everywhere and then you wouldn't need the nested grid. If your content is nested, you can use `display: contents` to flatten the hierarchy in CSS

  ```css
  & .addTransaction {
    /* ... */
    column-gap: 5px;

    /* ... */
    & .buySell { 
      display: contents;

      & button {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a grid library instead of creating your own. Pure-CSS has a nice grid thats very lightweight.

https://purecss.io/grids/

If you want to create your own grid, then do it in a more modular way.
I did an module for my own projects where filesize was critical and used box-layout for the grid itself. You can check it out here for a starting point.

https://github.com/domis4/wnderlvst-grid/blob/main/index.js

your react template would then look like this:

```html
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-xs-6">Buy</div>
    <div className="col-xs-6">Sell</div>
</div>
<div className"row">
    <div className="col-xs-12">token</div>
</div>
<div className"row">
    <div className="col-xs-6">quantity</div>
    <div className="col-xs-6">price</div>
  [...]
</div>
```